# Twitter HMACSHA1 Signature Creation C#

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement Twitter sign in via C# & I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error - "Could not authenticate you" which isn't that helpful. To try to diagnose the problem I want to make sure that the signature creation is working correctly.

Twitter's documentation page for signature creation is [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html). I have written a simple unit test that should generate a signature based on the values specified in the documentation. However the test fails as I get a different signature string. Are the values in the documentation wrong or is is#t the code I'm using? However all the C# Twitter code I've seen uses similar hashing code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TwitterSignatureCreation() {
  var signingKey = "kAcSOqF21Fu85e7zjz7ZN2U4ZRhfV3WpwPAoE3Z7kBw&LswwdoUaIvS8ltyTt5jkRh4J50vUPVVHtR2YPi5kE";
  var baseString = "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%25";

  var hmac = new HMACSHA1( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( signingKey ) );
  var hash = hmac.ComputeHash( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( baseString ) );

  var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String( hash );
  var expectedSignatureString = "hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=";

  Assert.AreEqual( expectedSignatureString, signatureString );
}

Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=>. 
Actual:<hOhJgzPMpZtXHCTeluIS1VdHUH8=>.
```

Comment: You didn't completely copied `baseString` from documentation page.

Comment: I definitely did copy the whole thing

Comment: Believe it or not but you didn't. Complete string is: "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%2520signed%2520OAuth%2520request%2521"

Comment: That works, thanks!! But on their documentation page under "Creating the signature base string" it says "This will produce the following: Signature base string" & the last characters are "Gentlemen%252C%2520a%25". I have checked the HTML source & the missing bits are there. Strange it wasn't rendered by Chrome.

Comment: That's an issue of html display. The complete string is really there, but it's display is distorted (because it's very long and without any whitespaces), so it's hard to copy-paste it correctly indeed.

Comment: Omg @Evk you are the man ! I wasted hours because of that same mistake